# Como ver qual é o application pool de um website iis 6?

Tags: iis, asp

Não manjo de iis.
Como faço para saber qual é o application pool de um website no iis 6 ?
O website está em ASP Classico, tem algum padrão ?

Comment: Você quer saber qual o pool que está rodando, ou qual que ele precisa para funcionar?

Comment: @Randrade Cara, os dois, pq eu tenho um site aqui que já está rodando e precisava criar um outro com os arquivos desse site pra mexer nele.